# ElasticSearch: Sort document based on combination of parent nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I'm trying to sort ES documents by combining numeric fields found in the root document with fields found in nested documents.  For simplicity let's say I want to sort on `doc['score'] + doc['nested.score']`.

Example mapping and a couple of data documents are here: http://pastebin.com/9sdMphsR

A naive (and wrong) approach since it tries to access `doc['score']` directly is:

```
POST /testing/stuff/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "mode": "max",
            "script": {
                "inline": "doc['score'].value + doc['variations.score'].value",
                "lang": "expression"
            },
            "order": "desc",
            "nested_path": "variations"
        }
    }
}
```

What's the correct way to go about doing this?  I realize I could copy the root-level `score` into each nested document, but if I can avoid doing that I'd prefer to.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST /testing/stuff/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "_script": {
      "type": "number",
      "script": {
        "inline": "def max=java.lang.Integer.MIN_VALUE; for(obj in doc['variations.score']){ if (obj > max) max = obj; }; return doc['score'].value + max",
        "lang": "groovy"
      },
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

And the `variations` field needs to have `"include_in_parent": true` for the script to be able to access the nested values.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  But it doesn't seem to work for me.  When I attempt this (with changing `max` to a float instead of int), `max` always evaluates to 0 and the returned value is simply the parent's `score`.  `variations` is a nested datatype, not a simple field.

Comment: What ES version is this?

Comment: I'm currently running version 2.2

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: `variations` needs to have `"include_in_parent": true` otherwise I don't see a way to access the nested objects' values.

Comment: Ah yes, I realize that duplicating the data within the parent object is an option, I was hoping for a solution which didn't require duplication of data.

Comment: I tried this in the past and now, as well, and I don't see a way to access those nested fields' values. I'd be happy and thankful to see a working solution without copying to parent the values.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Looks like for now I'm going to have to duplicate the parent data into the nested doc and do everything within the nested doc.